# How to preserve DB Connection in multiple xunit tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I got the service class which do basic CRUD Activities and I would like to run all tests together.

At the moment, I can run the test one by one.  But if I run the tests by choosing the test class, it just ran the random test first and failed other tests showing the error:

```
The connection string property has not been initialized.
```

[image]

The reason is that I am using `using` clause in my service and it gets rid of the current connection after the first test.

**CashupService.cs**

```
public class CashupService
    {
        private PJDbContext _context;

        public CashupService(PJDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<int> InsertCashUpRecord(CashupModel model)
        {
            using (IDbConnection conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {
                var parameters = new
                {
                    JobID = model.JobID
                    , Description = model.Description
                    , Amount = model.Amount
                    , User = model.UserCreated
                };

                return await conn.ExecuteAsync("dbo.InsertCashUpRecord", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);                
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CashupModel>> GetCashUpRecords(bool Latest, DateTime? From, DateTime? To)
        {
            using (IDbConnection conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {
                var parameters = new
                {
                    Latest = Latest
                    , From = From
                    , To = To
                };

                return await conn.QueryAsync<CashupModel>("dbo.GetCashUpRecords", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> InsertCashUpLog(CashupLogModel model)
        {
            _context.CashupLogs.Add(model);
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

The error goes away if I don't use `using` clause in my 2 Get methods.  But AFAIK it's a good practice and I don't want to get rid of that `using` clause.

My Fixture to initialize the connection:

```
public PJFixture()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PJDbContext>();

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=westwood;User Id=johnsmith;Password=xxx1234;");

            context = new PJStudents.DbContexts.PJDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);  
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
        public PJStudents.DbContexts.PJDbContext context { get; set; }
    }
```

**CashupServiceTests.cs**

Here I created DbContext and Service in the Constructor and in theory, shouldn't it be created again when it runs another test?

```
public class CashupServiceTest : IClassFixture<PJFixture>
    {
        PJFixture _fixture;
        CashupService _service;

        public CashupServiceTest(PJFixture fixture)
        {            
            _fixture = fixture;
            _service = new CashupService(_fixture.context);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_Return_CashUpRecords_With_Latest()
        {
            var result = await _service.GetCashUpRecords(true, null, null);

            Assert.NotEmpty(result);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_Return_CashUpRecords_With_Dates()
        {
            var result = await _service.GetCashUpRecords(false, new DateTime(2017, 3, 2, 10, 10, 10), DateTime.Now);

            Assert.NotEmpty(result);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_Insert_CashupLog()
        {
            var model = new CashupLogModel();
            model.Amount = 5;
            model.UserCreated = "tester";
            var result = await _service.InsertCashUpLog(model);

            Assert.True(model.LogID > 0);
        }
    }
```

Could you please suggest how I should write the tests and run them in one go?

If I create another test classes for each test, that error will go away, but there are going to be multiple files in my test files.

May I know the best practice and how you guys are doing that?

Comment: They are test, they just run once, as long as you don't use a production db(and you shouldn't for integration test) you can safely remove the using and share the context.

Comment: @Sxntk the using is in the class under test!